# How to automatically assign a TFS work item to a particular person/role

Tags: tfs

I would like to customize a Work Item Type in TFS to automatically set the Assignee to a particular role. For example (to compare to another Issue Tracker), in JIRA the default Assignee is the Project Lead (so that any ticket not otherwise assigned, gets automatically assigned to whatever person is designated in the role of Project Lead). Can I do something similar in TFS?

So, I realize that one difference between JIRA and TFS is that TFS doesn't (to my knowledge) have the concept of "Roles". The closest thing to that is "Groups", but unlike Roles, Groups can have multiple people (which may be the restricting factor in this problem). I know how to configure a TFS Work Item so that only a certain Group gets listed in the "Assign To" field, but I would like to go a step farther, if possible, and create a custom Group with just one member (e.g., "Issue Guru") and then set up the work item to get automatically assigned to that person.

I'm trying to replicate the Jira functionality here, and maybe there is just no good way to do it in the TFS framework. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can customise your Work Item Type Definition to have a default name in the "Assigned To" field for all Work Items in the Team Project. Is that what you're after?

Comment: That's close, but we have dozens of projects with several WITs in each. So if that name ever changes, we'd have a lot of WIT edits to make. If instead I could have a "Role" ("Group"?) in the `AssignedTo` field, I would only have to change the name once in Group Management when a new person takes on that role.

Comment: You could create a Group in Each Team Project and make it so that all work items are assigned to the group, yes. You would need to configure TFS to allow you to assign to a Group, and create the same group on all team projects.

Comment: That sounds very promising. Can you tell me how to "configure TFS to allow you to assign to a Group"? (And make it an answer so I can give you credit!)

Answer (score 1):

There's a Step by Step Guide on [Ivan Fioravanti's Blog](http://ivanfioravanti.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/assigning-a-work-item-to-a-group-in-tfs/) for enabling it.

If you are unfamiliar with customising Work Item Types, have a [look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243849.aspx) [at](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/) [the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236914.aspx) [links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718795.aspx) (stolen from Grant Holliday's blog).

Comment: That gets me closer. Following those instructions, the "Assign To" dropdown list only includes the people (or person) in the specified group. But the initial (default) value is still empty -- the User still has to click the field and select the person in the list. What I need is some way to force it to default to the first person in the list, but I'm guessing that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried this in production but here is something I tried quickly and it seems like it could work.

You can set the default value to a Group by editing work item template in template editor. 
Just select Assigned to field and add a DEFAULT rule like shown in the image below.

[image]

This will also require you to create one or more groups (one global or maybe one per project). Once you set this up you won’t have to make any updates in the future but only manage people who are in the groups.

Comment: You broke off your instructions one step too soon. Once you create a DEFAULT rule, what do you set it to? I went in and Tried to set it to `[project]\MyTestGroup`. I then created a new Issue and the "Assign To" field (correctly) displayed `[MyTestProject]\MyTestGroup`, but when I tried to save the ticket, I got this error: "Save failed. TF20015: 'MyTestProject]\MyTestGroup' is not in the list of supported values.'